# What is the difference between "baño" and "tocador"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

In Mexico *baño* is used at home, restaurants, hospitals, but in English the words are bathroom and restroom.

Answer (score 3):

"Baño" refers to the place where we have the shower or the bath at home and it stands for "toilet" or "restroom" in English.
"Tocador" is a furniture with a mirror (which can be placed on a bedroom). Women use it to make up or retouching their make up, brushing their hair, etc.
There is a room called "tocador" just like the furniture and is function is exactly the same.

This is a "tocador" (furniture):

[image]

Comment: The D.R.A.E doesn't agree with you. "Tocador" is NOT only a furniture: "Aposento destinado al aseo y peinado de una persona." [Room destined for cleanliness and hair-dressing of a person" https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZvyFMlt|ZvzUXTr

Comment: It is not only furniture but the room called "tocador" has the same function as the furniture I described.

Comment: Nice answer! I also see the mention of _tocador_ to the place outisde the toilet where, in public places like restaurants, women would make up.

Comment: *Tocador* often stands for the room it's in ([metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)), even though the DRAE doesn't include that meaning. This should clarified in the answer, I think.